# ¿Como puedo rellenar con ceros mi fecha python?

Tags: python, date, jupyter, dataset, pyspark

Buenas noches quiero convertir el formato de mi fecha y que se rellene con ceros de esta forma 00-00-0000

este es mi codigo

```
covid=covid.select('Date')
covid.show(5)

+--------+
|    Date|
+--------+
|3/1/2020|
|3/2/2020|
|3/2/2020|
|3/2/2020|
|3/3/2020|
+--------+
only showing top 5 rows


covid = covid.withColumn('Date', regexp_replace(col('Date'), "/", "-"))
covid.show(5)

+--------+
|    Date|
+--------+
|3-1-2020|
|3-2-2020|
|3-2-2020|
|3-2-2020|
|3-3-2020|
+--------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

quiero que mis fechas se rellenen con 00-00-0000 de esta forma como puedo hacerlo Gracias

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Tu columna "Date" en el fondo no es más que una cadena. Pero ya que esa cadena representa una fecha, sería más correcto convertirlo al tipo de dato `datetime`, ya que este tipo de dato permite operaciones con fechas (agrupar por mes, resamplear, comparar, y muchas más) y también permite definir el formato con que queremos convertirlas de nuevo en cadenas para visualizarlas.

Si este es tu dataframe original (en el que las fechas son en realidad cadenas):

```
>>> print(df)
       Date
0  3/1/2020
1  3/2/2020
2  3/2/2020
3  3/2/2020
4  3/3/2020
```

el primer paso sería convertir esas cadenas en verdaderas fechas, así:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
```

Con esto cada elemento de esa columna es de tipo `datetime`, lo que significa que por ejemplo podríamos extraer el mes de cada una de ellas, la distancia en días entre cada una y la siguiente, y otras operaciones con fechas. Pero además, cuando muestres el dataframe ya se mostrará de otra forma, que es la que pandas usa por defecto, que será Año-Mes-Dia, todos con 0 por la izquierda si es necesario:

```
>>> print(df)
        Date
0 2020-03-01
1 2020-03-02
2 2020-03-02
3 2020-03-02
4 2020-03-03
```

Observa un detalle. Pandas ha entendido que el formato original de tus cadenas "3/1/2020", significaba "mes/dia/año". Si no era así, sino que debería ser interpretado como "dia/mes/año", entonces debes pasar el argumento adicional `dayfirst=True` a `pd.to_datetime()`

De cualquier forma, el formato en que te lo muestra prácticamente es el que pedías y quizás ya te sirva así. Si insistes en querer verlo como dia-mes-año, puedes volver a convertir el objeto datetime en cadena:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print(df)
```

De este modo ya aparecerá así:

```
         Date
0  03-01-2020
1  03-02-2020
2  03-02-2020
3  03-02-2020
4  03-03-2020
```

Pero ten en cuenta que de nuevo esa columna será una vulgar cadena y no un objeto datetime, con lo que pierdes las posibilidades que éste te brinda.

Por desgracia no hay forma de decirle a pandas que use el formato "%d-%m-%Y" sólo a la hora de mostrar las fechas, sin cambiar el hecho de que internamente sigan almacenadas como objetos datetime. Al menos no es posible hacerlo en una interfaz de solo texto. Si trabajas con Jupyter Notebook o Google Colab en los que las tablas se pueden volcar en HTML, entonces puedes hacer uso de un "styler", que no afecta a lo que contiene la tabla, sino a cómo se muestra.

```
# df es tu tabla original, con cadenas
# Con esto lo convertimos a datetime
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True)
# Y con esto lo volcamos con el formato deseado, sin cambiar el dato en sí
df.style.format({"Date": lambda t: t.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")})
```

[image: Resultado]